# Not being able to add a textView to LinearLayout through code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am a beginner of android, and was studying the layout.

What i am trying to do is i am trying to add a textView to a LinearLayout through code, and the application stops with the error that the application has stopped unexpectedly. The code is:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout abc = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.cLayout);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Text Changed!!!!");

    abc.addView(tv);
```

And in the xml, id is set like: android:id="@+id/cLayout".

I know there are better ways to do it, but i want to know why this doesn't work. Contents of textView are changing just fine. Also i have also tried

```
    LinearLayout abc = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main);
```

What am i doing wrong? One thing is clear that i am accessing uncreated items (unassigned pointer).

**Edit**
Main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cLayout"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:id="@+id/myTV"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Attach exception stacktrace, please.

Comment: Agree with @Ash.  We need more details before we can help.  You say it's a NullPointerException - presumably, this is on the line abc.addView(tv).  Can you post your main.xml?

Comment: plz share if you are geting any exception or any error ?

Comment: I have used java exception (try catch block) and there is a java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: what's wrong with your code ? nothing wrong there as per i can see.

Comment: And the worst thing is that Ash copy/pasted the code and it worked fine on his machine! See his reply.

Comment: Anyway do one thing.replace abc.addView(tv); with abc.addView(1,tv);

Comment: abc.AddView(tv,1) didn't work, same exception!

Comment: After a discussion with Ash on the chat, it turned out that the project required a clean and build. After that it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce it, and it works for me, no exceptions.

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/cLayout"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView  
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cLayout);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello Again!");

        ll.addView(tv);
    }
}
```

**UPD** When I posted your code, I got an exception, too. Make sure you call `super.onCreate()`.

Comment: Steps forward for me then? I mean by my understanding it should work. I am totally confused!

Comment: I'll try printing the exception then

Comment: Yep, that would help. I'm as confused as you are, because your code seems fine.

Comment: I have used java exception (try catch block) and there is a java.lang.ClassCastException, if this helps

Comment: And super.onCreate call is there, i didn't miss it. I posted the code from setContentView()

Comment: I'm new to this site. Is there some way to talk directly? It would speed things up a bit. At least I could tell you how to retrieve exceptions from Android. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3937/discussion-between-ash-and-speedbirdnine)

Comment: After a discussion with Ash on the chat, it turned out that the project required a clean and build. After that it works fine.